# How to fetch same response data in a variable in eve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, response, eve

Below is the response generated by eve python framework.

```
{
  "_status": "ERR",
  "_error": {
    "code": 422,
    "message": "Insertion failure: 1 document(s) contain(s) error(s)"
  },
  "_issues": {
    "_email": "value 'sbchcbhjcj@gmail.com' is not unique",
  }
}
```

I want this response to be store in a variable.

I want also to print that variable on console having all the response above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an event hook to print the response for each request type using the post-request event hooks described [here](http://python-eve.org/features.html#post-request-event-hooks) in eve's documentation.

Inside a `post_POST` hook for example, you have the response information which you can print like this:

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequest

def after_post_log(resource, request, r):
    try:
        log.info("Finished POST request. url={} body={}. Response={}".format(request.url, request.json, r.response))
    except BadRequest:
        log.error("Finished POST request. url={} malformed JSON body response={}".format(request.url, r.response))

app = Eve()
app.on_post_POST += after_post_log
```

Notice that the `log` initialization in the code above is omitted.